# NULL values in MySQL database after I set default '0' to the column

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table

I have the payouts table to whom I set the default as **0.000** for my `total_tips` column (extract from my table schema):

```
total_tips       | decimal(12, 4) | YES  |      | 0.0000 | <- Default set as '0.0000'
```

But now, can anyone explain why I have still `NULL` values inside my table:

```
mysql> select total_tips from payouts where id = 4157;
+------------+
| total_tips |
+------------+
|       NULL |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Before that I ran a `ALTER` command which look like this (to set the default value):

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE payouts change total_tips total_tips decimal(12,4) default 0 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *maybe* didn't set the value as `NOT NULL`, so the NULL value is accepted. You need to update your whole base with:

```
UPDATE payouts SET total_tips = 0 WHERE total_tips IS NULL
```

Comment: I thought that could be the reason but just wanted to confirm

Answer (score 3):

if you set defaults on existing columns in tables which already stores data then the existing rows are not automatically updated.

i mean this is only true for mssql and mysql. in oracle existing lines WILL BE updated.